# What type of moss is best suited for a hanging Kokedama (moss ball)?

Tags: houseplants, moss, kokedama

I have tried rock cap moss but it does not hold together very well. Works fine if you display the ball on a flat surface but I am looking to make one that will hang by a string.

Is there a specific type of moss that works best for this type of Kokedama?

I am aiming for something similar to the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While any moss *can* be used for Kokedama, some will hold together better than others.

Most commonly used is sphagnum (peat) moss. This is because of its prostrate growing habit, making it hold together better than most other mosses.